# The right way to add to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `.text()` to add to a `div`. I don't know how much I will be adding. But if I use `.text()` more then once it will just add the last one. I have used `.text(msg1,msg2,msg3)` and this does work for me, but i would like it if the text was more ordered. like after every msg a new line would start. I have tried to add spaces but that does not work and is not the way i want it. I just had a div, i tried adding, `<p>`'s to it, i tried `$("p:first")` tried by ID. I have included a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/G24aQ/12/

```
if(k1<10){
  msg1= "This will not space like a want." + "  "
  msg2= "I don know why not.      "
  msg3= "How come.       "
  $('#output1').text(msg1);
  $('#p').text(msg2);
  $('#output1').text(msg3+"      "+msg2+"       "+ msg1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can you use `<br/>` to add the messages in new lines.
2. You can use `html` instead of `text` and add it all at once. To add one by one, use `html` and `append` together.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/G24aQ/14/

```
if (k1 < 10) {
        msg1 = "This will not space like a want.<br/>";
        msg2 = "I don know why not.<br/>";
        msg3 = "How come.<br/>";
        $('#output1').html(msg3 + msg2 + msg1); //this will add all the three variables together into #output1 - replacing older content
        /*
        //To add one by one 
        $("#output1").html(msg3); // this will erase the older content so that you have a clean #output1 div
        $("#output1").append(msg2); //this will add to the existing content, will not over write it
        $("#output1").append(msg1); //this will add to the existing content, will not over write it
        */
}
```

Always keep in mind that `html()` & `text()` will erase everything in the selector and add the new content into it. `append` adds to the existing content. And, your HTML tags will be ignored if `text()` is used.

Docs for [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) & [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for extra info.

Comment: works perfect and easy to add to with append! I will use your example but i wonder what the difference is between using your answer and António Regadas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(id).append (code);` if you want to **append**, not to change.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember, html will only render excessive spaces as one. 
You have to use

```
 &nbsp;
```

or put each text inside a span tag with a right margin

```
<span style="margin-right:10px"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `append` for that, like:

```
if (k1 < 10) {
        msg1 = "This will not space like a want.<br/>";
        msg2 = "I don know why not.<br/>";
        msg3 = "How come.<br/>";
        $('#output1').append('<p>'+msg1+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg2+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg3+'</p>');
}
```

and use a html tag like `<p>` to make them appear in new lines.

You can also do it this way:

```
if (k1 < 10) {
   msg1 = "This will not space like a want.<br/>";
   msg2 = "I don know why not.<br/>";
   msg3 = "How come.<br/>";
   var e = $('<p>'+msg1+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg2+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg3+'</p>');
   $('#output1').append(e);
}
```